# Filter specific Strings in For loop using batch Script

Tags: batch-file

Directory structure `C:Test\client1,C:\Test\client2....`

Here I need to execute _Test.cmd files at time for specific clients only.

Please let me know how to filter the client names in this for loop using Batch script?

```
@Echo Off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
for /r C:\Install %%x in ("*_Test.cmd") do (
 ECHO [ !DATE! !TIME! ] Executing %%x ...
 CD %%~dx%%~px
 CALL _Test.cmd
 IF ERRORLEVEL 0 (
  ECHO [ !DATE! !TIME! ] Successful!
 )
)
```

Answer (score 1):

No idea how to distinguish "client name" from "not a client name".

If you mean "directory names" where each client has a directory, then:

```
@Echo Off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
pushd
for /d /r C:\test %%x in (.) do (
 ECHO [ !DATE! !TIME! ] Executing %%x ...
 CD %%~dpx
 CALL _Test.cmd
 IF NOT ERRORLEVEL 1 (
  ECHO [ !DATE! !TIME! ] Successful!
 )
)
popd
```

Notes:
  pushd/popd bracket saves the current directory and restores after `for` loop.

`for /d /r` means directories, recursive

Target "." means "all" - if you have a mask to apply, put that mask here.

`cd %%~dpx` is simply shorter than your version.

`if errorlevel 0` is always true under normal circumstances. `if errorlevel n` means "if errorlevel is n **or greater than n**". `cmd` can be forced to set `errorlevel` negative, but it's a contrived situation.

---

" i need to run _Test.cmd for only particular clients like client24,client15,client40."

Now if you'd said that to start off with....

```
@Echo Off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
pushd
for /f "delims=" %%x in (yourfileofclients.txt) do if exist "c:\test\%%~x\." (
 ECHO [ !DATE! !TIME! ] Executing %%x ...
 CD "c:\test\%%~x"
 CALL _Test.cmd
 IF NOT ERRORLEVEL 1 (
  ECHO [ !DATE! !TIME! ] Successful!
 )
)
popd
```

Comment: I mean, I have clients folders in the directory like client1,client2,....client60. But i need to run _Test.cmd for only particular clients like client24,client15,client40...

Comment: Thanks for your information. But one more issue Iam facing i.e.,

Comment: Thanks for your information. It is working fine for one module of application. But I have multiple modules which contains _Test.cmd batch files. I need to execute multiple batch files for specific clients and that to be for multiple modules. But one more issue Iam facing i.e., 
for /f "delims=" %%x in (yourfileofclients.txt) ->it is for specific clients and
 for /r C:\test %%x in ("*_regsvc.cmd") -> i need to use this for multiple modules. Iam unable to make two conditions at a time.